How do I add a link to my linkedin SVG on HTML
I have been trying to add a linkedin svg image to html linking it to my linkedin page. I have managed to get the image to show up locally however this does not work on browser (the image does not show, see image screenshot attached, however the link still works).
I have done some research and there is mention of using xlink and xmlns but I'm struggling to understand this. Why use a namespace that refers to w3 website?
The below example is given on W3 site however I want to incorporate my svg Linkedin icon image rather than a .jpg:
<svg height="200" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <image height="200" width="300" href="pulpitrock.jpg" / </svg>
The code I have currently is this which I know is inadequate:
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/dovedigital"><img id="linkedin" src="images/5296501_linkedin_network_linkedin logo_icon.svg"> </a>
Please help! I only know how to use HTML and CSS, I am a coding beginner.
Insert linkedin svg icon image which links to my linkedin page once clicked within my HTML VS code document.

The first svg is in fact a jpeg - just wrapped in a SVG which doesn't add any benefits. Check if your image URLs are accessible for logged out users. Why not use your own avatar/profile image (the one you've uploaded when editing your profile)?

<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/dovedigital" aria-label="Visit Dove Digital on LinkedIn">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#0A66C2" width="24" height="24">
    <path d="M20.447 20.452h-3.554v-5.569c0-1.328-.027-3.037-1.852-3.037-1.853 0-2.136 1.445-2.136 2.939v5.667H9.351V9h3.414v1.561h.046c.477-.9 1.637-1.85 3.37-1.85 3.601 0 4.267 2.37 4.267 5.455v6.286zM5.337 7.433c-1.144 0-2.063-.926-2.063-2.065 0-1.138.92-2.063 2.063-2.063 1.14 0 2.064.925 2.064 2.063 0 1.139-.925 2.065-2.064 2.065zm1.782 13.019H3.555V9h3.564v11.452zM22.225 0H1.771C.792 0 0 .774 0 1.729v20.542C0 23.227.792 24 1.771 24h20.451C23.2 24 24 23.227 24 22.271V1.729C24 .774 23.2 0 22.222 0h.003z"/>
  </svg>
</a>

is one way to do it

You don't need to make a whole SVG tag to use SVG images, instead you can just use an svg or normal image on the internet and use it in an <img> tag normally. In this example below I used a PNG image if thats ok, and it's also spaced out to make it easier to read.


<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/dovedigital">
<img id="linkedin" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/LinkedIn_logo_initials.png" style="height:14px;width:auto;display:inline" alt="Linkedin icon" />
Check out my Linkedin page!
</a>



